# Reason for why apparent acceleration of algebraic multigrid solve by addition of positive definite diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-solver, preconditioning, multigrid, conjugate-gradient, krylov-method

In passing I was told by someone that $K^{\prime}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, will be easier to solve by an algebraic multigrid preconditioned conjugate gradient (CG-AMG) solver than $K$, where $K$ is a discretized elliptic (2nd order) differential operator, that is symmetric positive definite, and
\begin{align*}
K^{\prime}=K+D,
\end{align*}
where $D$ is a positive definite diagonal matrix. For an example problem, I have observed that solving $K^{\prime}x=b$ consistently requires less CG-AMG iterations than the CG-AMG iterations for solving $Kx=b$.

I would like to understand why this is the case. So please, if you understand why this is the case I would appreciate your input.

$\textbf{Update -- following discussion in comments}$ with lightxbulb.

\begin{align*}
\lambda_{\text{min}}(K^{\prime})=\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},\|x\|_2=1}
(x^{\top}K^{\prime}x)=y^{\top}K^{\prime}y,
\end{align*}

here $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a unit length vector which satisfies $y^{\top}K^{\prime}y=\lambda_{\text{min}}(K^{\prime})$. Furthermore

\begin{align*}
y^{\top}K^{\prime}y\geq y^{\top}Ky\geq\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},\|x\|_{2}=1}x^{\top}Kx=\lambda_{\text{min}}(K),
\end{align*}

so that $\exists \epsilon_{2}\geq 0$, such that $\lambda_{\text{min}}(K^{\prime})=\lambda_{\text{min}}(K)+\epsilon_{2}$.

Similarly

\begin{align*}
\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},\|x\|_{2}=1}x^{\top}Kx=z^{\top}Kz
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
z^{\top}Kz\leq z^{\top}K^{\prime}z\leq\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},\|x\|_{2}=1}x^{\top}K^{\prime}x=\lambda_{\text{max}}(K^{\prime})
\end{align*}

so $\exists \epsilon_{1}\geq 0$, such that $\lambda_{\text{max}}(K^{\prime})=\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)+\epsilon_{1}$, finally

\begin{align*}
\kappa(K^{\prime})=\frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}(K^{\prime})}{\lambda_{\text{min}}(K^{\prime})}=\frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)+\epsilon_{1}}{\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)+\epsilon_{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: It changes the condition number of the matrix, note that the result is not the same once you do this. Let's take a simple example: $-\Delta u = \frac{f}{\tau}$ and set $D = \frac{1}{\tau}I$ then you get something like $(-\Delta +  \frac{1}{\tau}I)u = \frac{f}{\tau}$. The latter can be rewritten as $\frac{u-f}{\tau} = \Delta u$, i.e. time implicit diffusion for time $\tau$. It is similar to solving $\partial_t u = \Delta u$ with initial condition $u(0) = f$ and computing the solution at time $\tau$. It's clear that this takes fewer iterations for small $\tau$ compared to $\tau \to \infty$.

Comment: If $K$ is symmetric positive (semi-) definite, the condition number is $\kappa = \lambda_{\max}/\lambda_{\min}$. Now let $v_i$ be the unit eigenvector of $K$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$. Then it is the eigenvector of $K'$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i + \epsilon$: $K' v = (K+\epsilon I)v_i = \lambda_i v_i + \epsilon v_i = (\lambda_i + \epsilon) v_i$. It is clear that $\frac{\lambda_{\max}}{\lambda_{\min}} \geq \frac{\lambda_{\max}+\epsilon}{\lambda_{\min}+\epsilon}$. The smaller $\lambda_{\min}$ and the larger $\epsilon$ the more this helps, but it foesn't solve the same problem.

Comment: @lightxbulb, I am particularly interested in your second argument. I see that if the diagonal positive definite matrix $D$ is a multiple of the identity than the condition number will be improved. However, what if $D$ is a general positive definite diagonal matrix? In this case I have $\kappa(K^{\prime})=(\lambda_{\text{max}}+\epsilon_{1})/(\lambda_{\text{min}}+\epsilon_{2})$, for two non negative numbers $\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2}$.

Comment: How did you get this for $\kappa$?

Comment: In this case if $\epsilon_{1}$ is large enough and $\epsilon_{2}$ is small enough than $\kappa(K^{\prime})>\kappa(K)$.

Comment: @lightxbulb I will add this to the original question post.

Comment: How did you get $\kappa(K') = (\lambda_{\max} + \epsilon_1) / (\lambda_{\min} + \epsilon_2)$?;

Comment: @lightxbulb see the problem description above, I have added details on how I arrived to the expression in question. Recall that I am not assuming that $D$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you meant. Let's pick an extremely simple example with $D = \operatorname{diag}(\vec{\epsilon})$ and $A= \operatorname{diag}(\vec{\lambda})$. Then I can modify any of the eigenvalues of $A$ to increase them by different amounts. Notably this means that I can also make the condition number worse. The bigger problem though is that any such addition of $D$ regardless whether it is $\epsilon I$ or with varying coefficients, modifies the problem that you are solving. I would suggest picking a preconditioner or better solver. Or checking why you get close to singular matrices.

Comment: @lightxbulb I do not expect the solutions of $Kx=b$ and $K^{\prime}x=b$ to be the same.

Comment: My original question is just if there is something inherent in the algebraic multigrid algorithm that makes $K^{\prime}$ better suited for AMG treatment than $K$.

Comment: I don't believe it is specigic to AMG, but I could be wrong. My understanding is that $D=\epsilon I$ can change the condition number to be smaller, so it will help any iterative solver. An arbitrary $D$ can make the condition number worse, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why do you mention "close to singular matrices"?

Comment: I am not including $D$ to make the solve easier, it is just that I need to solve with $K^{\prime}$ and observe that it has been easier than with $K$ via AMG-CG. I wanted to explain it but doesn't look like it can be explained purely by referencing the condition number of each matrix.

Comment: Because adding $\epsilon I$ is typically employed in such cases (for close to singular or singular matrices), and in the special case where $\lambda_{\min}=0$ it turns a problem that doesn't have a unique solution (or potentially has no solution) into one that does. As far as your conjecture goes - it is likely that your $D$ matrices are such that they increase the smallest eigenvalue more than they increase the largest eigenvalue. You can try to compute the eigenvalues or condition number on some toy examples to check that conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

The computation in your update does most of the work towards a solution. You just need to note that $\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\varepsilon_2} \leq \frac{\max D_{ii}}{\min D_{ii}} =  \kappa(D)$, and that
$$
\kappa(K^{\prime})=\frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)+\epsilon_{1}}{\lambda_{\text{min}}(K)+\epsilon_{2}}
$$
lies in the segment that joins $\kappa(K) = \frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}(K)}{\lambda_{\text{min}}(K)}$ and $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2}$. Hence if you are summing a diagonal matrix with $\kappa(D) \leq \kappa(K)$ then you are always improving the condition number.

Comment: Indeed the condition $\kappa(D)<\kappa(K)$ guarantees an improvement. I believe the weight for the linear combination $(1-c)\kappa(K) + c\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2} = \kappa(K')$ is $\frac{\epsilon_2^2}{\epsilon_2^2+\lambda_{\min}\epsilon_2^2}$ so it is indeed a convex linear combination. Do you know how to write $\epsilon_1, \, \epsilon_2$ in terms of $K$ and $D$ explicitly? Clearly $\epsilon_1 = \lambda_{\max}(K')-\lambda_{\max}(K)$ but I was wondering whether there is something more specific.

Comment: I doubt there is more you can do for understanding $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ in terms of $K^{\prime}$ and $K$ unless you know more details about these matrices.

Comment: Another aspect about my problem is that $D$ is poorly conditioned. So I cannot use $\kappa(D)\leq \kappa(K)$.

Comment: @Tucker Then clearly you cannot conclude in general that $K+D$ is better conditioned than $K$; take $K=I$ for instance.

Comment: I never said that $K+D$ is better conditioned than $K$. The conditioning idea was something that was being explored with lightxbulb. My original question is if there is something specific about algebraic multigrid that makes $K^{\prime}$ better suited for said algorithm than $K$.

Comment: @Tucker The convergence of conjugate gradients depends on the condition number. So there is something specific about $CG$ that makes this faster to solve as long as you have $\kappa(D) < \kappa(K)$ as Poloni identified. In fact you should be able to find an example where it makes it slower. Note that I believe that it can occur that $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2} < \kappa(K) < \kappa(D)$, so the condition $\kappa(D) < \kappa(K)$ is too strong.

Comment: @Tucker You should be able to find an example where it makes it slower* when $\kappa(K) <\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2}$. In your tested cases I assume it's usually the case that $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2} < \kappa(K)$. To make a clean experiment you should form the algebraic multigrid preconditioning matrices $P$ and $P'$ respectively for $K$ and $K'$ and compute the condition numbers for $PK$ and $P'K'$.